# PHP timezone issue with America/Chicago

Tags: php, datetime

On one of my server when I when running this code

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
print_r($now->getOffset());
```

I get 0 as output while on other server it is coming as expected -18000.

Setting default timezone to UTC in php.ini is not helping out. The issue seems to be with America/Chicago timezone as when I am doing the offset for America/Phoenix or America/Los_Angeles I am getting expected results. I am not sure what can be the issue with America/Chicago, please suggest a way to debug this.

Not sure if this can be a clue, but function DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(); returns 416 results on server where timezone works fine and 415 on server with America/Chicago timezone issue.

Comment: Any differences in PHP versions?

Comment: Hi @Evert server with the issue is having php 5.4 while the other one is having 5.5.

Comment: Setting the default timezone in php.ini is fine. But i would recommend you doing it in your php script as well. This way you can be 100% sure that the timezone picked is always right.  Just set this on the top of your script date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

Comment: even if I am trying to calculate timezone difference between UTC and America/Chicago I am getting 0, it seems issue might be how DateTime class picks time zone offset of America/Chicago to UTC, I am not able to find php internal timezone database to confirm

Comment: @arpitr it sounds like a bug to me, so I would look at the _full_ PHP 5.4 version number and see if there's anything fixed in later versions.

Comment: The timezone database doesn't really matter. America/Chicago hasn't changed much in the last 8 or 9 years.

Comment: I see that on my local system with PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27) it works fine but the server with issue has PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2014 12:59:36), version is same unless built date makes a difference.